# Is it possible to set a hashmap variable in HTML code

Tags: html, hashmap

Is it possible to set a hashmap varialbe in HTML code ?
for example:

```
<form name="f1234">
  <input type="text" name="map['foo1']" value="dog" />
  <input type="text" name="map['foo2']" value="cat" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.f1234.map['foo1'].value="pig";
</script>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<form name="f1234">
  <input type="text" name="map[foo1]" id="map_foo1" value="dog" />
  <input type="text" name="map[foo2]" id="map_foo2" value="cat" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('map_foo1').value="pig";
</script>
```